# SQL: Trying to put a series of "count"s results into a table

Tags: sql, select, count

I have to do a series of 'counts' with SQL to figure out drug use. Im pretty new to SQL/SAS but Ive written the following simple (and prob terrible macro):

```
        %macro rxs (title, data, zz);
        Title &title &zz;
        proc sql; 
            select count (studyid) as NumberofRxs from &data where zz=&zz; 
            select count (distinct studyid) as NUMofPATIENTS from &data where zz=&zz; 
            select count (studyid) as numRXswithSTATIN from &data where zz=&zz and exposed=1; 
            select count (distinct studyid) as numPATIENTSwithdrug from &data where zz=&zz and exposed=1;
            select count (studyid) as numRXSnodrug from &data where zz=&zz and exppsed=0;
            select count (distinct studyid) as numPATIENTSSnodrug from &data where zz=&zz and exposed=0;
                quit; %mend rxs;
```

The results come out fine... its just a bit of a mess. It'd be nice if I could dump them into one simple table. Like I said, Im new to this, so the solution might be super simple.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having all of those different selects, you can combine them into something like this:

```
select  count (studyid) as NumberofRxs,
        count (distinct studyid) as NUMofPATIENTS,
        count (Case when exposed = 1 Then studyid Else null End) as numRXswithSTATIN,
        count (distinct Case when exposed = 1 Then studyid Else null End) as numPATIENTSwithdrug,
        count (Case when exposed = 0 Then studyid Else null End) as numRXSnodrug,
        count (distinct Case when exposed = 0 Then studyid Else null End) as numPATIENTSSnodrug

from &data where zz=&zz;
```

Notice how I have a case statement in some of the counts. Count ignores values that are null. Since you only want to count studyid based on exposed, the case statements will return null if exposed is the wrong value. Then count will ignore it.

Comment: Thanks. I figured there was probably a much simpler way of doing that!